# In a makefile, how can I paste a directory path to every file in a list of files?

Tags: makefile

If I define the following variables in my makefile

```
REPORT_DIR = ./reports

REPORT_TARGETS = my_report.html another_report.html

clean: 
    rm -f $(REPORT_DIR)/$(REPORT_TARGETS)
```

When I execute `make clean` the report directory is only pasted to the first report target.

```
rm -f ./reports/my_report.html another_report.html
```

My goal is that executing `make clean` would produce

```
rm -f ./reports/my_report.html ./reports/another_report.html
```

How can I paste `./reports/` to all elements of `REPORT_TARGETS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the addprefix function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions):

```
TARGETS_WITH_PATHS := $(addprefix $(REPORT_DIR)/, $(REPORT_TARGETS))
```